# Show elements with certain css-class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show all elements with a certain css class, without success. The elements are hidden with `display:none;`

```
$('myClass').each().show();
```

This doesn't do anything. How would I need to fix this?

Comment: You could start by reading the documentation to find out *why* it does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.myClass').show();
```

Comment: thx - tried this before, but missed the point before the class-name... :-/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){
        $(this).show();
      });
```